# Is there any way to collect user specified audit logs of grafana (using grafana free version), loki and prometheus within openshift k8s cluster

Tags: openshift, grafana, audit-logging

I am working on a issue - Grafana audit log collection and publish . In this we need to get user specified audit logs . Is there anyway to do this . We are using (grafana free version)

Since we are not using grafana enterprise version cannot get user -specified audit logs from grafana . So need to know whether there are any other optios to do this.